# Xpath using matches and Regex working in Xpath tester but in code throwing InvalidSelectorException Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

**HTML**

```
<div class="top-section" style="" xpath="1">
         <input id="role" value="admin" hidden="">
            <small>Welcome </small> <b style="">8828024404, MCGM</b>
            <a href=""><img alt="Attendance" width="" height="" src="css/assets/images/logo.png"></img></a>
            <a href="/logout" class="float-right logout">Log Out</a>
        </input>
</div>
```

**String to search**

```
8828024404, MCGM
```

**Xpath Expression**

```
//b[matches(text(),'[0-9]{10}, [A-Za-z]*')]
```

**Exception**

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable
>   to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //b[matches(text(),'[0-9]{10}, [A-Za-z]*')] because of the following
>   error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The
>   string '//b[matches(text(),'[0-9]{10}, [A-Za-z]*')]' is not a valid
>   XPath expression.   (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)   (Driver
>   info: chromedriver=2.42.591088
>   (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium supports XPath 1.0 version while `fn:matches` is from XPath 2.0.

If you want to *match bold text that starts with 10 digits before comma*, you can try below XPath

```
//b[string-length(substring-before(., ','))=10 and number(substring-before(., ','))]
```

Let me know in case you have more constraints to required element

Answer (score 0):

Quite not sure about your exact *usecase* why you want a *xpath* to search for a *Regex*.

However the resultant text seems to be a part of the *Welcome Message* and I feel your *usecase* may be to extract the text which will be **dynamic** e.g. **8828024404, MCGM**.

In this case you can use either of the following solutions:

- XPath 1:

  ```
  //div[@class='top-section']/input[@id='role' and @value='admin']//b
  ```
- XPath 2:

  ```
  //div[@class='top-section']/input[@id='role' and @value='admin']/small[contains(.,'Welcome')]//following::b[1]
  ```